# How to Destroy Object from static method in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

Destroy() method   is not accessible in static method

```
  public static void Die()   
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

But Destroy() is only accessible if:

```
public void Die()
{
     Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: `Destroy` is a `MonoBehaviour` method. Why exactly do you want to make `Die()` `static`?

Comment: To make it accessible on another scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a non static function from a static function but you can do the opposite.

> I need to make it accessible on another scripts

Make the Die function to be a non `static` function. Let's say that this script is named `OtherScript`.

```
public void Die()
{
     Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Then from another script, you can access it by finding the GameObject the `OtherScript` script is attached to with the `GameObject.Find` function then use the `GetComponent` function to get the `OtherScript` reference from the GameObject:

```
OtherScript otherScript;

void Awake()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectOtherScriptIsAttachedTo");
    otherScript = obj.GetComponent<OtherScript>();
}
```

You can now call the `Die` function with `otherScript.Die()`. *Note that you must replace "NameOfGameObjectOtherScriptIsAttachedTo" with the name of GameObject the `OtherScript` script is attached to.*

Comment: TLDR: "because I need it accessible from other scripts" is not what you use `static` for.

Comment: @Draco18s Yeah, not what static is used for. New Unity users tend to use static because they don't know how to access data or function in another script. Happened to me too when I was new to Unity but I hope OP can now see how to do this without making the variables or function static.

Comment: I'm not sure it ever happened to me, at least, not like this.  Probably because the first language I ever really *understood* and worked with in a fluid manner was ActionScript 2. The idea of objects as instances was a fundamental Thing. If I needed access to the player I could navigate the scene hierarchy if I needed to. Dirty as hell, sure, but valid and without `static` everywhere.

Comment: @Draco18s Well I guess we're all different. Some people figure things out easily. I went with static then I found the GetComponent function and that was a life saver to me. Also, not knowing how to access data or function in another script did not just make people use static, it also caused them the "NullException" error. A problem that gets its new question everyday.

Comment: Oh sure. I totally understand why it happens, it just didn't happen to me. And I'm only guessing as to why it didn't happen. Doesn't mean I don't have *other* problems either.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer for your answer. Exactly, the "NullException" error for prefabs made me to use static function.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks more like you actually want to do what [Programmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917277/7111561) shows.

I'm just adding this because your title asks `How to Destroy Object from static method in Unity C#`

---

If you really need it to be static (e.g. in a static class) you could use it like this

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static void Die(GameObject obj)
    {
        Object.Destroy(obj);
    }
}
```

but to be honest this is needed in very few cases. It might be helpful e.g. in an Editor script where you don't have any Component executing your code.

Answer (score -1):

cannot kill a single `static` object, it dosnt work that way. please refer to the answer [here.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1112414/cant-destroy-gameobject-in-static-method.html)

the following excerpt is from the above link, and should explain for you...

*I think perhaps you've misunderstood the 'static' keyword a little bit.

To clarify, a bit... Imagine you have a class called 'Vehicle'.

A none-static variable means 'every vehicle has its own copy of this variable'. We might say 'every instance of vehicle has its own copy of the variable.

A static variable means 'there is only 1 of this value shared by all vehicles'. Here we'd say 'all instances of vehicle share the variable.

Following on from that, functions are a little harder to picture, but they work in much the same way:

A none-static function operates on an instance of the vehicle. The result is that it can use the 'this' operator (it makes sense!) and access both none-static member variables of it's instance, and the shared static ones

A static function isn't tied to an individual instance of a vehicle, so the 'this' operator doesn't make any sense (what would 'this' be?). It still makes sense for it to be able to access static variables, but again none-static ones don't make any sense - who's version of the variable would it be referring to?

Your 'Die' function looks like it is designed to operate on a given instance of your enemy. i.e. you are expecting calling 'Die' to mean 'kill this please'. As a result it should not be static. You'll also need to access the 'gameObject' variable, not the 'GameObject' type.*

Comment: I think with some formatting and other editing this answer would be ok. As is, it is hard to read (though probably correct).